# How to use multiple websites/development urls on Hyper-V & Default Switch

Tags: networking, dns, hyper-v

I develop on Windows 10, so I use Hyper-V to run my Ubuntu VM. I don't want to mess around with complex networking whenever I go from a wired to wireless connection, so I just use the Default Switch.

Hyper-V sets the hostname for my development machine to nginx.mshome.net

I work on about 6 different website, so I have them all setup at hostnames like:

- alpha.nginx.mshome.net
- beta.nginx.mshome.net
- gamma.nginx.mshome.net

For the longest time Hyper-V was pretty consistent with what IP address it assigns my VM, so I had these other hostnames just setup as static entries in my hosts file. I maybe had to go in and fix it every couple weeks, but that wasn't a big deal.

After installing the Windows 10 October 2018 Update, and the subsequent VPN x Blue Screen error that caused me to have to run netsh interface ip reset and netcfg -d, Hyper-V is now assigning a different IP address to my VM on virtually every boot.

I can't just set the VM to a static IP, because Hyper-V even changes the subnet for the Default Switch.

I tried setting up multiple network interfaces and forced dhclient to use a different hostname for each, but since they were all on the same subnet only one wanted to work on a time.

I need some kind of solution to either get Hyper-V to use and assign a consistent IP to my VM running on the Default Switch, or some kind of way to setup DNS aliases on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I've set this up using the Hyper-V Private Switch, using Internet Connection Sharing of my wireless connection to the Private Switch. I then just give the VMs a static IP, setup a host file entry, and go on my way. Since it's using ICS, that keeps the same subnet.

The only issue I have with this is that every so often Windows 10 forgets how to pass traffic over ICS. The cFosICS tool (https://www.cfos.de/en-us/cfosspeed/cfosics.htm) has a reset option that usually works. If not, cFosICS also lets you disable and reenable ICS via command line, so you can save a script to kick it into gear.